# Why the second then in promise works earlier?

Tags: javascript

```js
function l() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $('#root>div>div>main>div>div:nth-child(3)>div>div:nth-child(2)>div>div>div:nth-child(2)>div:nth-child(2)>div>div:nth-child(2)>div>div:nth-child(1)>div:nth-child(1)>table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(7)>div>div:nth-child(2)>a>span')
            .each(
                function() {
                    var t = $(this);
                    Promise.resolve().then(_ => new Promise(resolve =>
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                console.log('1')
                                t.click()
                                resolve();
                            }, 200)
                        ))
                        .then(
                            _ => new Promise(resolve =>
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    console.log('2')
                                    $('body>div:nth-last-child(1)>div>div>div:nth-child(3)>div:nth-child(2)>button>span').click()
                                    resolve();
                                }, 200)
                            )
                        )
                }
            )

        resolve();
    })
}

function page() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function() {
            fo = $("#root>div>div>main>div>div:nth-child(3)>div>div:nth-child(2)>div>div>div:nth-child(2)>div:nth-child(2)>div>div:nth-child(2)>div>div:nth-child(2)>div>ul>li:nth-last-child(1)")
            fo.click()
            console.log('翻页')
            resolve();
        }, 2000)

    })
}
Promise.resolve().then(l()).then(page())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The consequece is that function page excute earlier?why it comes?How to do to correct that?I want to first excute L and then excute page.I have tried many times,it doesn't work.How to use promise.then().then () in correct way.Please tell me.

Comment: The snippet is not demonstrating your problem. Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: *(You've too much resolve in your code... )*

Comment: You are not resolving the `l()` promise properly. It is resolving BEFORE `page` actually, because you are calling `resolve()` before the inner promises end.

Comment: You are calling the functions, then referencing them. `Promise.resolve().then(l).then(page)` Also weird you are using Promise.resolve() like this.